# Best way to return data back to driver from spark workers

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

We're facing performance issues running big data task on a single machine. Task by design is memory and compute intensive and is running an optimization algorithm (branch and bound algorithm) on huge data sets. A single EC2 c5.24x large machine (96vCPU/192GiB) is now taking over 2 days to complete the task. We have tried to optimize the code (multiple threads, more memory, parallelism, optimized algorithm) but looks like there's a limit to how much we could achieve and doesn't sound like a scalable option as the data set is growing and we're adding more use cases to it.

Thinking of distributing this in to smaller tasks and have it executed by multiple workers in spark cluster. Output of the task will be a single Gzipped JSON (2- 20 MB in size) and by distributing i want each worker to build smaller JSONs or RDD chunks which could later be merged at the driver side.

Is this doable? Is there a limit on how much data each worker can send back to the driver? Or is it better to store each worker output to some database (S3) and then merge at driver side? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: why do you want to merge specifically in the driver?

Comment: At the end of the task, we need a final merged output and I believe driver is the best component to do that as it can ensure consistency.

Comment: it's always advisable not to collect any results back to driver, as it is not scalabale in almost all the cases. Can you please paste relevant portions of your code here, it will be beneficial for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to collect data from executors to driver and combine them there. It makes the driver a bottleneck and it will run into frequent resource related issues. The best option is to let the executors process the data and produce JSONs. You can leave the output JSONs as is which will help in reprocessing them again. If you are too worried about size of these JSONs or want to combine them to send to another process then you can use a file utility to combine them or you can use `dataframe.coleasc(1)` to generate one output file.